# The meaning of "to be x years out from putting two and two together"

Tags: meaning

During a conversation someone said that he is x years out from putting two and two together with gadolinium poisoning. What is the meaning of "to be x years out from"? I know the meaning of "putting two and two together" ... Thanks!

Comment: ... a long way off ...

Comment: Unclear what this means: "putting two and two together with gadolinium poisoning".

Comment: gadolinium - an x-ray contrast  chemical

Comment: Yes I know that (rolls eyes) but what does the _whole quoted thing_ mean?

Comment: He said it actually using the letter eks?  Then yes, it means a long way off (in time), or some unspecified length of time.  Or did he say something like "10 years out"?  Then he means 10 years away (in the future or in the past).

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your comment of another answer, I'm not sure you're parsing the question properly:

> I'm x years out

is to imply you're a number (x) many years away from accomplishing:

> putting 2 and 2 together with

Making a basic understanding of ...

> [The topic of] gadolinium poisoning.

He's not saying that he has been poisoned with gadolinium, rather that he's studying people who have.

Answer (score 0):

**out**   [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/133395?rskey=vPGvTp&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid) the sense of:

> Revealed, made known, no longer a secret.

As in:  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/out)

> In the time following; afterward: "to gauge economic conditions **six
>   months out**" (Christian Science Monitor).

In this case, gadolinium's use and its medical complications became apparent ~ 6 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

X is used in maths as an undetermined number, so to be "x years out" from something means an unknown amount of time, but a time that is none the less measured in years.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but I suspect the OP is more interested in the "years out" part than the "x" (though yours is technically a valid interpretation of the question).

Comment: Hello: So the person who is suffering from gadolinium poisoning put two and two together  x years ago? Thank you for your help once again!